# Matching last and first bracket in gsub/r and leaving the remaining content intact

Tags: regex, r, replace, gsub, punctuation

I'm working with a character vector of the following format:

```
[-0.2122,-0.1213)
[-0.2750,-0.2122)
[-0.1213,-0.0222)
[-0.1213,-0.0222)
```

I would like to remove `[` and `)` so I can get the desired result resembling:

```
-0.2122,-0.1213
-0.2750,-0.2122
-0.1213,-0.0222
-0.1213,-0.0222
```

## Attempts

### 1 - Groups,

I was thinking of capturing first and second group, on the lines of the syntax:

```
[[^\[{1}(?![[:digit:]])\){1}
```

but it doesn't seem to work, ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iC7pC0/1)).

### 2 - Punctuation

The code: `[[:punct:]]` will capture all punctuation [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iC7pC0/2).

[image: Match]

### 3 - Groups again

Then I tried to match the two groups: `(\[)(\))`, but, again, no lack [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iC7pC0/3).

---

*The problem can be easily solved by applying `gsub` twice or making use of the [`multigsub`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/qdap/docs/multigsub) available in the `qdap` package but I'm interested in solving this via one expression, is possible.*

Comment: Why not just [**`\[|\)`**](https://regex101.com/r/iC7pC0/4)? as in `gsub("\\[|\\)", "", "[-0.2122,-0.1213)")`? Or am I missing something here

Comment: Why not, `^\[|\)$`  or `^[[:punct:]]|[[:punct:]]$`?

Comment: This removes the first and last characters of each component of `v` :   `gsub("^.|.$", "", v)`  .  Also it seems they are fixed widths so this would work: `read.fwf(textConnection(v), widths = c(1, 7, 1, 7, 1))[c(2, 4)]`

Comment: Or simply `gsub("[[)]","","[-0.2122,-0.1213)")`  as we can be quite confident there won't be parentheses or brackets out of the first and last in the processed text.

Comment: If the nchar is the same, then `substr(x, 2, nchar(x) - 1)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @AvinashRaj as it didn't occur to me in that precise moment but the solution is super fine.

Comment: @zx8754 `nchar` is the same in this particular case but I would rather have solution that does not necessarily depend on that as it may not be the same in some other cases.

Comment: That sounds an XY problem, I guess next step will be to separate the two numbers in two columns of a DF... so: `regmatches(input(regexpr('\\[(.*),(.*)\\)',input)` sounds a better fit (maybe prefixed by as.numeric... [demo of what I mean](https://regex101.com/r/iC7pC0/6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using lookaheads and lookbehinds in Perl-style regular expressions.

```
x <- scan(what = character(), 
text = "[-0.2122,-0.1213)
[-0.2750,-0.2122)
[-0.1213,-0.0222)
[-0.1213,-0.0222)")

regmatches(x, regexpr("(?<=\\[).+(?=\\))", x, perl = TRUE))
# [1] "-0.2122,-0.1213" "-0.2750,-0.2122" "-0.1213,-0.0222" "-0.1213,-0.0222"
```

Comment: Sounds overkil and, while at it, I would separate the numbers with two capture groups